# Using 'gdalwarp' in Python script for Grass

Tags: python, grass-gis

I'm writing a Python script that aims to re-project various LANDSAT tiles into a common projection and then import the tiles into Grass. The script at present is shown below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import sys
import glob
import grass.script as grass

def import_tifs(dirpath):
    for dirpath, dirname, filenames in os.walk(dirpath):
        for tile in filenames:
        if tile.upper().endswith('.TIF'):
                full_path = os.path.join(dirpath, tile)     
                name = os.path.splitext(tile)[0]        
        rename = name[:-4] + '.' + name[-2]
        new_path = os.path.join(dirpath, rename)
        re_project = 'EPSG:32643'
                grass.message('Importing %s -> %s@%s...' % (tile, name, dirpath))               
        grass.run_command('gdalwarp',
                  '-t_srs',
                  re_project,
                  full_path,
                  new_path)
                grass.run_command('r.in.gdal',
                                  flags = 'e',
                                  input = full_path,
                                  output = name,
                                  quiet = True,
                                  overwrite = True)

def main():                                 
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:                          
        for directory in filter(os.path.isdir, os.listdir(os.getcwd())):
            import_tifs(directory)
    else:
        import_tifs(sys.argv[1])           
if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

I'm having real trouble using the 'gdalwarp' command to reproject the LANDSAT tiles. I keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Simon/Documents/import_landsat3.py", line
76, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/Simon/Documents/import_landsat3.py", line
73, in main
    import_tifs(sys.argv[1])
  File "C:/Users/Simon/Documents/import_landsat3.py", line
31, in import_tifs
    new_path)
  File "C:\GRASS64\etc\python\grass\script\core.py", line
189, in run_command
    ps = start_command(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\GRASS64\etc\python\grass\script\core.py", line
167, in start_command
    args = make_command(prog, flags, overwrite, quiet,
verbose, **options)
  File "C:\GRASS64\etc\python\grass\script\core.py", line
124, in make_command
    raise ScriptError("'-' is not a valid flag")
grass.script.core.ScriptError: "'-' is not a valid flag"
```

I'm assuming this is related to '-t_srs' but I haven't been able to work out a way around the problem - can anyone suggest how to do this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried calling `gdalwarp` using `os.sys`? Check this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6669/converting-projected-geotiff-to-wgs84-with-gdal-and-python) for more details on the topic.

Comment: Thanks - I've given this a try, but have got the error: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable                          What module do I need to import to use gdalwarp with os.sys in a Python script?

Comment: what about trying os.system('gdalwarp ... ')?

Comment: Thanks - this has worked! Could you tell me why os.system worked and os.sys didn't?

Answer (score 2):

Try the subprocess module:

```
import subprocess
cmd = ['gdalwarp','-t_srs',re_project,full_path,new_path]
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout,stderr=proc.communicate()
exit_code=proc.wait()

if exit_code: #Oops, something went wrong!
    raise RuntimeError(stderr)
else:print stdout
```

Comment: Thanks for this - I've managed to get the code to work using os.system as suggested by @dmci but I'm going to try using the subprocess module as I haven't come across it before.

Comment: From the python docs for [os.system](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system): "The [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module provides more powerful facilities for spawning new processes and retrieving their results; using that module is preferable to using this function."