# How do you change units from meters to kilometres?

Tags: grass-gis, resolution

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using ‘gdalwarp’ in Python script for Grass](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37821/using-gdalwarp-in-python-script-for-grass)

I wonder how i could fit my cells to 10 km... Therefore is in meters... and the resolution is different (0.16164). I need this for create a buffer zone. But it is in meters. I will like to learn solving. If I made a project like WS84, it is the same. What should i do? My map is probabilities.

Thanks

**g.region -p**
projection: 0 (x,y)

zone:       0

north:      70.38082

south:      29.80918

west:       -9.52082

east:       37.35478

nsres:      0.16164

ewres:      0.16164

rows:       251

cols:       290

cells:      72790

Comment: You appear to be asking about how to *project* a grid from geographic coordinates using GRASS. Please search our site for solutions to that problem.  (They all seem to use `gdalwarp`.)