# Error using gdalwarp in EPSG:4326

Tags: python, coordinate-system, gdalwarp

I tried to change the projection of AMSR-2 in Python using:

```
'gdalwarp -geoloc -t_srs EPSG:4326 C:\GW1AM2_201301311114_050A_L1SGBTBR_1110110.vrt C:\test100.tif'
```

It said there are something wrong with 'EPSG:4326'(Invalid syntax). I do not know why?

Comment: what do you get if you put a quote around the EPSG:4326 string like ```"EPSG:4326"```

Comment: 1) Would it depend what Python version you are using? 2) Assuming you are running the command in a command shell, and you typed Python in the shell to engage Python interpreter: I've ran into the syntax issue when executing a command while Python interpreter is engaged. I fix the issue when I open in the OSGeo4W.bat command shell and then run the command straight away, and not type Python first to engage Python. So maybe try that..?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe python does not find the EPSG file in your file system.

Try `"+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"` (with the quotes) instead.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I have tried it, but it still does not work. It said that there are "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" in the place of " which is at the end of "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs".

Comment: Can you try the same in a command line box? Maybe you have to double the quotes in your python call.

Comment: This might help too: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37821/using-gdalwarp-in-python-script-for-grass. can you add a part of your python code?